# Firebase doesn't send data ordered in my case

Tags: firebase

I have ordered data in firebase. Order is critical for me. But firebase can't send ordered in my case.
*(PS: Persistence enabled. I tried this at Android and IOS client. Result is the same.)*

First, there are 3 items and I received them.

```
cache: 1,2,3      firebase:1,2,3
```

Then, I closed app and updated data(inserted 3 item).

```
cache: 1,2,3      firebase:1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I opened app and **limitToLast(1)** method to get last item.

```
cache: 1,2,3,6    firebase:1,2,3,4,5,6
```

And the error is coming..

I registered this node with **childAdded** event. The **childAdded** callback triggered this sequence:

```
1,2,3,6,4,5
```

I don't want to sort items. What should I do?

I finished example project.
https://github.com/muzafferyilmaz/FirebaseOrderTesting

### Update

Relevant code snippet from the linked github project:

```
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.i(TAG, "onChildAdded: " + text);
        mAdapter.addData(text);
    }
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that causes the behavior, it's impossible to say anything.

Comment: I think case is obvious. All methods I used written above. Nevertheless I will create example Android project for the case and post it.

Comment: There are several different ways in Firebase to retrieve the results shown in the question, (childAdded? query? .value? orderedBy?) and the implementation of that code can vary the result. Let's take a look at your code and also a sample of your Firebase structure (copy/paste and format please!) so we can help out.

Comment: Code FTW. Also, read about [arrays in Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase) (hint: don't use them. Use [push ids](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push)).

Comment: I tried string as key. Result is same. Why everybody judges me, nobody wants to understand me. Im preparing example. Sorry for im late because of busy. Closing the question doesnt help us!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Added example project. Can you check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems are caused by the fact that you're ignoring the second argument that is passed to `onChildAdded`:

```
void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName)
```

That `previousChildName` is the key of the element that the new child needs to be added after. By ignoring it, you're losing any guarantee of ordering.

```
private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String text = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.i(TAG, "onChildAdded: " + text +  " after s");
        mAdapter.addData(text);
    }
```

Logcat then shows:

```
onChildAdded: 1 after null
onChildAdded: 2 after a
onChildAdded: 3 after b
onChildAdded: 6 after c
onChildAdded: 4 after c
onChildAdded: 5 after d
```

If you execute these in order, you get:

- `a: 1`
- `a: 1, b: 2`
- `a: 1, b: 2, c: 3`
- `a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, f: 6`
- `a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, f:6`
- `a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5, f:6`

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has a section on [Indexing and Ordering](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html) the data returned by Queries. Can you not follow one of the methods there, based on your data layout?

In a factory, I do have the following which does sort by the data field.

```
angular.module('MyApp').factory('AllPlayers', ["FireBaseData", "$firebaseArray",
    function(FireBaseData,$firebaseArray) {
        var AllPlayersRef=FireBaseData.child('Players');
        return $firebaseArray(AllPlayersRef.orderByChild('FirstName'));
    }
]);
```

Data Structure:

```
Players
- 1 (Key)
    Email: ""
    FirstName: "John"
    LastName: "Doe"
    Number: 11

- 2 (Key)
    Email: ""
    FirstName: "Jane"
    LastName: "Smith"
    Number: 15
```

The factory will return my data with Jane Smith being 1st, followed by John Doe, using the FirstName field as the order.

If this is not working, then I would have agree with @Frank-van-Puffelen that sample code would be needed to help you further.

Comment: My item's keys are integer and they are sequencial. A node's key and and priority are indexed automatically. So, my items already ordered. Anyway, I tried orderByKey(), result is same.